# In Cordova is there a way to always target a specific device for one or more specific platforms when running all?

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

When I type in:

```
cordova run
```

The Cordova app is run in all added platforms. However, Android doesn't run because it always seems to need a specified target to run. When I run it specifically for the Android platform it needs a target, like:

```
cordova run android --target=Nexus_S_API_25
```

Since I like to run all platforms at once nicely, I am looking for a way to let Cordova know it should target Android in a specified emulator. Is there a way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your question was answered, please upvote and accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if your emulator is already running. Cordova is printing the following message in that case:

> No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to specify default targets in a config file. You can take a look at [the logic for choosing the run target](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/55d7cf38654157187c4a4c2b8784191acc97c8ee/bin/templates/cordova/lib/run.js#L59) for the android platform yourself. AFAICT by checking code in `cordova-cli` and `cordova-lib` repos, nothing but the command line options are passed to the platform commands.

However, as you can tell from the code, if no target is specified, *devices will take precedence over emulators*. Among the emulators *a started emulator will be chosen if available*. So if you have your preferred emulator running and no android devices connected, you should be fine.